# Configure Pytest discovery to ignore class name

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Pytest's default discovery rules will import all Class starting with `Test` that do not have an `__init__()`. I have a situation where this causes an incorrect class to be imported.

I am testing a django project that uses Factory Boy. http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to build out a Django model named `Testimonial`.

like so:

```
class TestimonialFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Testimonial
```

This issue is that `factory.Factory` does not have an `__init__()`. So py.test sees `Test`imonials and tries to run. Which in turn tries to insert a record into the database within the pytest discovery phase (hilarity and failures ensue).

I have hacked a workaround by changing the pytest.ini to look for Test classes to start with Check instead of Test:

```
[pytest]
python_classes=Check
```

This is not really what I want. Is there any way to explicitly tell py.test to ignore a test of a certain name?

Answer (score 27):

Here is a simple solution that I use, but has some overhead.

```
class DisablePyTestCollectionMixin(object):
  __test__ = False

class TestimonialFactory(DisablePyTestCollectionMixin):
  pass
```

Based on: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1879

Comment: Great. This works for me. However I find it better not to use a mixin and just mark the class with `__test__ = False`.

Comment: it seems to work on older version, not work on pytest-7.3.1

Comment: In my case I was importing the class from elsewhere, and all I had to do was set the `__test__` attribute like this:
`from messages import TestMessage` and then 
`setattr(TestMessage, "__test__", False)`
I'm only on pytest 7.1.2 though.

Answer (score 11):

This is an older question, but it seems to be the only relevant hit on stackoverflow, so I thought I'd leave an alternate answer here for posterity.

Another workaround involves disabling **all** classname-based discovery and relying on subclass discovery *only*. In other words:

In your config file: (`setup.cfg` or `pytest.ini`):

```
[pytest]
python_classes =
```

And in your test files:

```
class TestWillNotBeRun(object):
  # Not a subclass of unittest.TestCase, so not collected regardless of name
class TestWillBeRun(unittest.TestCase):
  # Still okay to use TestName convention for readability
  # It just doesn't actually do anything.
class StillGoingToBeRun(unittest.TestCase): 
  # Relying on subclassing means *all* subclasses will be picked up, regardless of name
```

One of the advantages of this is that it doesn't require changing your non-test class names. For a library where these classes are exposed to users, there can be good reasons for not renaming. Also, it doesn't require massive renaming of test classes (since they can now be literally anything). Finally, unlike name-based discovery, it's unlikely that non-test code will somehow be a subclass of unittest.TestCase. (I'm sure someone out there is an exception.)

The drawback is that you must ensure that *all* your test classes must be subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`. For all of my code, that's already true, so there was no cost. That's not necessarily universally true, though.

Answer (score 4):

You should use pytest.ini file with glob matching for class name.

```
#pytest.ini file
[pytest]
python_classes = !Test
```

This will make pytest ignore all test classes starting with Test.

More info here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions

Answer (score 2):

Put all tests into files starting with `test_` and add this to your `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
python_files=test_*.py
```

This will instruct pytest to discover tests only in `test_*.py` files.

Comment: The factory in question is used in a test file with that prefix.

Comment: You could also consider moving `TestimonialFactory` to a `conftest.py` file (I presume it's used in a py.test fixture).  Or simply rename it not to start with `Test`.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration options seem to only be prefixes or globs, so I don't think you can exclude a specific file name:
https://pytest.org/latest/customize.html#confval-python_classes

I think renaming your class (MyTestimonialFactory) or moving it outside of the discovery path would be the easy fix here.

That said, I still think you could use one of the collection hooks to skip or remove that class during collection.  Perhaps `pytest_pycollect_makeitem`, as described here:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#collection-hooks